# How do you type hint Vue props with typescript interfaces?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Really hitting my head against a wall on this one. I remember working in Angular that TS interfaces can be used to type hint parameters.

I'd like to do the same for props in Vue.

Any ideas? Code is as follows but the check is only made against a standard Object so passing in ANY object is valid:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Person from './../models/Person';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    person: {
        type: Object as () => Person
    },
  },
});
```

Interface as follows:

```
export default interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like: `props: { person: ... } as { person: Person }`??

Comment: I think this work with classes but not interfaces.. May have to bite the bullet and apply the interface to a class and specify that one.

Error for that solution is `Person only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`

Comment: Trick seems to be to create an interface and implement it on a class. Luckily, the class can have an abstracted layer and it still let's it by. E.g `Person (interface) -> BusinessOwner (class) -> Director(class)`. If the type is set to `BusinessOwner`, `Director` is allowed.

Comment: I think sadly in this case the answer is "it can't be done". The reason for this is simple - Typescript exists exclusively at _compile_ time, and Vue prop types are validated at _runtime_. You can use it for IDE completion etc., but I don't think actual validation is going to work here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep - so turns out you can't use interfaces. Makes total sense in hindsight when you consider things like type-hinting in PHP7.

The answer is to apply the interface to a class and the type hint using that class instead. With abstraction layers, my worries about having to apply the wrong class to a type hint were unfounded as any class extending or implementing the `Person` class will be a valid value to pass to the `person` prop.

```
export default interface NameInterface {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

```
import NameInterface from './../interfaces/NameInterface';
export default class Person implements NameInterface {

    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    constructor( firstName: string, lastName: string ) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Person from './../models/Person';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    person: {
        type: Person
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 16):

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Person from './../models/Person';

export default({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    person: {
        type: Object as ()=> Person
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

If you're using classes instead of `Vue.extend` you can use the `@Prop()` decorator (from `vue-property-decorator`) to have interfaces as type parameters.

With OP's interface:

```
export default interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

The class declaration would become:

```
import {Component, Prop, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Person from './../models/Person';

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends vue {
    @Prop() person : Person;
}
```

([Source on GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6850#issuecomment-337767353))

---

You could also use `PropType<FooBar>` in place of `Object as () => FooBar` (see the end of this <s>[medium article](https://frontendsociety.com/using-a-typescript-interfaces-and-types-as-a-prop-type-in-vuejs-508ab3f83480)</s> [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20220718055057/https://frontendsociety.com/using-a-typescript-interfaces-and-types-as-a-prop-type-in-vuejs-508ab3f83480)), but it has the same issues as OP mentioned.

warning: the archived url gets stuck in a refresh loop unless you [disable javascript](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000891.htm)

Comment: do use `vue-class-component` and `vue-property-decorator`, it's a lifesaver and game-changer. Just look at the accepted answer - what a trashy construct you need to build to achieve the typescript development basics

Comment: The medium article seems to be 404, or rather redirecting do advertisement.

Comment: @luckydonald I've added an archive.org link to the same article, but it gets stuck in a refresh loop unless you disable JavaScript. Unfortunately that seems to be the best I can do :/